# How to generate turtles at random time intervals and at random points in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am quite new to NetLogo, so I need some help figuring out a few things.
I have a requirement to generate turtles at random points and intervals when the go button is clicked. I have written the code mentioned below, but it generates turtles only when I click on the go button, and they are not moving properly. The go button I am using is a forever one, not the single-step button. Kindly help me where I am doing wrong.

```
  to go
    repeat num-students[
    every t [
    set t random 60
    create-students 1 [
    set xcor random -32 - 32
    set ycor random -13 - -15]
    ask students [
    set size 2
    set color blue
    set heading ( 90) 
    forward random 10
  ]]]
end
```

Comment: How do you want them to move? Without knowing that we cannot give suggestion on how to make them move properly.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to indent your code, that makes it much easier to see which command fits into which block. You can do this by simply highlighting all of your code and clicking `tab`.

I am not very familiar with the `every` primitive but the following code works as intended and I can't seem to reproduce your problem of no extra turtles being made. Maybe it is just that your time interval is too big?

```
to setup
  ca
  set num-students 5
  set t random 5
end

to go
    every t [
      set t random 5
      create-students 1 [
        set xcor random -32 - 32
        set ycor random -13 - -15
      ]
      ask students [
        set size 2
        set color blue
        set heading ( 90) 
        forward random 10
      ]
    if count students >= num-students [stop]
    ]
  
end
```

I removed the `repeat num-students[]` part since it didn't add anything to the code. It just makes you repeat the every command a few times inside each tick. Instead, I used `if count students >= num-students [stop]` in order to stop when the desired amount of students is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend not using "every" -- it executes something every specified number of seconds in real time, which is very different from at random *simulated* times. You need code that decides at which ticks turtles are created. (I did not even know "every" existed until seeing this and have never seen it used.)